# Scrolling with wxwidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

good day,

I have made the scrollbar visible on my panel, but for the life of me I do not know how to capture the scroll events. How is this done? im using versio  2.8.

Even with wxScrolledWindow the scrollbar is visible but how does one get the event and then process it?

I have tried using connect() and no luck.
Pleas point me to an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Several points:

1. Using `wxScrolledWindow` is different from using the individual, standalone, `wxScrollBar` controls. To capture events for the former, you use `wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_XXX` events and the corresponding event macros, while for the latter you use `wxEVT_SCROLL_XXX`.
2. Typically you should be using `wxScrolledWindow` which takes care of scrolling automatically, i.e. you rarely need to catch any events, are you sure you really need to do this?
3. Look at the [scroll sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/samples/scroll/scroll.cpp) for many examples of using different scrolled windows if you hadn't already.
4. Do yourself a favour and switch to a supported 3.0 version instead of a decade old 2.8, there is really no reason to start a new project using 2.8 nowadays.

Comment: Thanks VZ, I have tried to Connect() my panel to all of the available wxEVT_SCROLL_BOTTOM events and wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_BOTTOM event, and just simply display a message when the event is captured. Is connect() not the correct way?

Comment: All of event table macros, `Connect()` and `Bind()` (in 3.0) should work. The `BOTTOM` event is probably only sent when you use "End" key to scroll to the very right or bottom, so you might be just not generating it. Again, are you sure you need to handle it at all?